# What can prevent an attribute from being created in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Everything doesn't seem to be too hard but I've spent hours yet still can't get it working.

If I do Category.create(:name => "foo") in the rails console, a new category with its name gets created beautifully.

```
(0.2ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "categories" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-09-16 15:40:01.218700"], ["name", "foo"], ["updated_at", "2014-09-16 15:40:01.218700"]]
(14.5ms)  commit transaction
=> #<Category id: 38, created_at: "2014-09-16 15:40:01", updated_at: "2014-09-16 15:40:01", name: "foo">
```

However, if I do it on the pages something goes wrong. My Category model has only one attribute which is "name", and I want all of them to be listed on my category index page.

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <b><%= category.name %></b><br />
        <% category.products.each do |product| %>
            <%=  product.title %><br />
        <% end %>
      </li>
    </ul>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "Create new category", categories_new_path %>
```

If I create a new category with its name in the console, it appears on the page with its name with no problem. But if I create it on the page, there's a category created with its name attribute being "nil". So please help me figure out where the problem is. I'm quite new to rails.

Here's my categories_controller.erb

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  # load_and_authorize_resource
  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.new(params[:name])
    if @category.save
        redirect_to categories_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end
end
```

And here's my new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Category</h1>

<%= form_for(@category) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', categories_path %>
```

Here's what appears in the server after I hit the submit button.

```
Started POST "/categories?locale=en" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 00:02:42 +0800
Processing by CategoriesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZdXcC/uEMA/jhGoGhYvp4lSHHfi/tmlm3CovJcYizJ0=", "category"=>{"name"=>"fwefewfw"}, "commit"=>"Create Category", "locale"=>"en"}
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "categories" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-09-16 16:02:42.806041"], ["updated_at", "2014-09-16 16:02:42.806041"]]
(21.2ms)  commit transaction
```

Note that there's no "name" being inserted in the sql statement.
I sense I missed something that is very basic. Well forgive me for being a newbie and thank you for the help!!

Comment: If you look at the `Parameters` line, the `name` is contained inside the `category`. You should, henceforth, use `params[:category][:name]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your tags, i think you are using rails 4 so you need to permit your attributes first. You can do it by this:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  # load_and_authorize_resource

  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)
    if @category.save
      redirect_to categories_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

For details checkout [**`Strong Parameters in Rails`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)

Comment: @jeremylinlin good to hear that and do checkout the link i posted in my answer. You'll get to know why we use it like this in rails

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
@category = Category.new(params[:category])
```

If you're on Rails 4, you should use the strong params and add the following method to your controller:

```
def category_params
   params.require(:category).permit(:name)
end
```

And then change the Category.new line to:

```
@category = Category.new(category_params)
```

That's the new "safe" way to accept user-generated data in Rails models, and works really well once you get used to it.